# Docker: Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'host-machine'

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

Hello I am new to docker and I have installed Docker on my Windows 10 PC and was running fine with Windows containers when I switch it back to Linux containers it throws below error:

```
Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'hostname' because the object was not found. The object might have been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running.
at New-Switch, <No file>: line 121
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 411
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line 36
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<SwitchDaemon>b__0() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 305
   at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
```

Can anyonre provide further process what should I do or any article to continue further steps, thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error is pointing out, why not check if `Virtual Machine Management service` is running or not. If not, just run as administrator `net start vmms` to start the service

Comment: I have done this many times as suggested by many including you sir but having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

For me it happened after windows update. Recompiling MOF worked.

```
MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof
```